# expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token line 28

Tags: c, pid, nagios

I'm having problems compiling some code to check if pids are still alive. Yes, I am new to C, and I apologize about the formatting. I cannot seem to solve this issue.

Errors returned when trying to compile.

```
cc pid_check_with_sig.c -o pid_check_with_sig
pid_check_with_sig.c: In function ‘kill’:
pid_check_with_sig.c:28: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>    //Needed for standard I/O
#include <stdlib.h>   //Needed for exit
#include <signal.h>   //Needed for kill function

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   FILE *pf;
   static char pidnum;
   pf = fopen(argv[1], "r");

   if (pf == NULL){
      printf("Pid file doesn't exist\n");
      return 2;
   }
   else {
      do  {pidnum = getc(pf);         /* get one character from the file */
      }while (pidnum != EOF);     /* repeat until EOF (end of file) */
      fclose(pf);                 /* Close pidfile */
   }
   return pidnum;
}
pid_t kill(pid_t pidnum, int sig) {        /* function declaration */
   {
      if ((kill (pidnum, 0)) == -1){
         printf("The pid %s is no longer valid", pidnum);
         return 2;
      }
      else ((kill (pidnum, 0)) == 0){
         prinrf("The pid %s is valid", pidnum);
      }  return 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Typo error `prinrf` in function `kill`.

Comment: Too many syntax errors.

Comment: this line: else ((kill (pidnum, 0)) == 0){ has a syntax error, it is missing the 'if'  it should be: else if ((kill (pidnum, 0)) == 0){  There is also an unnecessary (but not harmful) set of braces {} in the kill function

Comment: This is a recursive function, with a poor exit condition.  I suspect it will perform recursion forever as it continually calls itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
else ((kill (pidnum, 0)) == 0){
```

should be:

```
else if ((kill (pidnum, 0)) == 0){
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if( condition )
{
    do something;
}
else if(condition)
{
    do something;
}
else
{
    do something;
}
```

You can't use "condition" after just "else". So "else ((kill (pidnum, 0)) == 0)" so you should use "else if" here.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use condition in else statement. Either change

```
else ((kill (pidnum, 0)) == 0){
     prinrf("The pid %s is valid", pidnum);
  }
```

to

```
else {
     prinrf("The pid %s is valid", pidnum);
  }
```

or write else if statement as:

```
else if((kill (pidnum, 0)) == 0){
     prinrf("The pid %s is valid", pidnum);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the last else case print statement.
I think that should fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Please check for the last "else". After else, there is no condition. In the case you want to add condition after else, use else if instead
Remove the last "}".

Answer (score 0):

```
pid_check_with_sig.c:28: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
```

`else` cannot have a conditional, it needs to be `else if (statement) {}`.
Your compiler was seeing `((kill (pidnum, 0)) == 0)` as a statement with no terminator, followed by a separate code block:

```
else
{
    //evaluate kill(pidnum,0), compare with 0 and forget the result.
    ((kill (pidnum, 0)) == 0)  //note the missing ';'
}
{
    printf("The pid %s is valid", pidnum);
}
```

you also had a typo in the `printf` call.

The lines in question should be:

```
28:    else if ((kill (pidnum, 0)) == 0){
29:        printf("The pid %s is valid", pidnum);
30:    }  return 0;
```